# PowerBuilder - Error with SetFilter(string) - Expression is not valid

Tags: filter, builder, powerbuilder

I have an application that generates some reports. I use some filters in data that is retrieved.

```
wf_gen_filtro_conceptos()

//PROBLEM---------------
dw_rp1.setfilter(string(is_filtro) + " " + "or IsNull(causa)")
//----------------------
dw_rp1.filter()
dw_rp1.sort()
dw_rp1.groupcalc()
```

In `wf_gen_filtro_conceptos()` the variable `is_filtro` is set up. 
The problem is when I use `setfilter()`. I can't concatenate those strings to create the new filter. If I use one of those strings, for example, `IsNull(causa)` on its own, there's NO problem.

Comment: We need to see what is in the instance variable is_filtro to figure this out.  Also no need to add a space separately between the instance variable and second part of your expression, simply use " or IsNull(causa)" instead of " " + "or IsNull(causa)" but this is more nitpicking as it doesn't change anything. Also, SetFilter does have a return value to check for errors but again more nitpicking.

Answer (score 3):

Add a line to concatenate the string before you use the SetFilter method.
Something like

```
ls_filterstring = is_filtro + " " + "or IsNull(causa)"
dw_rp1.setfilter(ls_filterstring)
```

This way you can examine what is happening with your filterstring in the debugger.  If is_filtro is NULL then the entire string will be NULL.

If is_filtro is being set make sure the quote marks, if any, in the string are correct.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that is_filtro has an invalid column, or an invalid value, or is_filtro is null, or is_filtro is empty.

---

Initialize is_filtro to something meaningful.

This works if you want all values.

```
is_filtro = "(1 = 1)"
```

---

If is_filtro is empty ("")

```
dw_rp1.setfilter(string(is_filtro) + " " + "or IsNull(causa)")
```

setfilter would be effectively

```
dw_rp1.setfilter(" or IsNull(causa)")
```

---

If is_filtro is null

setfilter would be effectively

```
dw_rp1.setfilter()
```

---

Your filter needs to match the column datatype.

Suppose that causa is a string column and you intend to filter values A, B, and C.

**Wrong**

```
is_filtro = "causa in (A, B, C)"
```

**Right**

```
is_filtro = "causa in ('A', 'B', 'C')"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are combining different filter clauses you need an and between them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for answering my question.
I've tried the stuff you suggested but it's still throwing the same error..

Here is the function that set the filter up.

```
choose case  is_filtro_ca
case  ''
    messagebox("Filtro", "Is filter 1")
is_filtro = ""

case '*'
    messagebox("Filtro", "Is filter 2")
is_filtro = ""

case else
    messagebox("Filtro", "Is filter 3")
is_filtro = "causa in (" + is_filtro_ca + ")"

End choose
```

This function is called when a button "Show empty lines" is pressed. I put those messages an it always prints "Is filter 2".

Comment: This means is_distro = '*' and that it is set to "".  When you concatenate you get `or IsNull(causa)` which is no valid filter.  But the whole code is required.  Also check the return value after 'Setfilter'.

Comment: Yes, but when I use both filter by their own, (I main separately, once at a tme) it works fine. I think the problem is the way I'm concatenating the filters but I can't figure out why.

Comment: Print the value of the concatenated string and try to use it interactively in the datawindow painter.  This way, you will be able to test various possibilities.